# Is a .vdi file for VirtualBox Cross-Platform?

Tags: cross-platform, virtualbox

I have a .vdi file on a Windows 64 bit.
Can I use the same .vdi file on a different machine like a Linux 32-bit, without problem?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes - the file itself contains nothing in it that is specific to the host operating system. You will need to make sure you bring along the virtual machine definition file (it is XML) usually ending in .vbox for recent versions of VirtualBox.

That being said, despite the virtual hard drive being fine, your guest virtual machine may not work on 32-bit linux of you had configured the guest as a 64-bit operating system. There may be other weird hardware differences too, though the best thing to do is to just make a backup and try it. It may adjust to the new hardware and just need a simple reboot.